# Renaming Functions during runtime in PHP

Tags: php, debugging, pecl, php-extension

In PHP 5.3 is there a way to rename a function or "hook" a function.

There is the `rename_function()` within "APD" which has been broken since ~2004.  If you try and build it on PHP 5.3 you'll get this error:

`'struct  _zend_compiler_globals' has no member named 'extended_info'`

This is a really easy error to fix,  just change this line:

`GC(extended_info) = 1;`

to

`CG(compiler_options) |= ZEND_COMPILE_EXTENDED_INFO;`

I modified my php.ini and the APD shows up in my phpinfo() as it should.  However when i call `rename_function()` the PHP page doesn't load and I get a segmentation fault in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Is there anyway to fix APD to work with a modern version of PHP?  Or is there another method to rename functions?  **Why on earth is vital feature not in php!??!?!** (Gotta love python :)

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but can you show me your code?

Comment: @Glaslos  as far as I know none of this works any more.

Comment: I got APD to work. So maybe I can help you...

Comment: @Glaslos so wait,  does rename_function() work on php 5.3.8?

Comment: I think I only tried 5.3.6 (current version in ubuntu afaik)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The up-to-date runkit extension can be found on http://github.com/zenovich/runkit
It supports all contemporary versions of PHP released for the time being (from 4.4 to 5.4+). This runkit is official and supported.

Sincerely,
Dmitry Zenovich

Comment: Thank you! This is a useful extension.

Answer (score 2):

Runkit trunk is 5.3+ compatible.

```
svn checkout http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/runkit/trunk runkit
cd runkit
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

Add extension=runkit.so to php.ini (or runkit.ini in conf.d)

In order to use `runkit_function_rename()` you will also have to recompile php with the `--enable-maintainer-zts` configuration flag. (Damn you zend!)

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is a bit old, but I was recently looking for a way to rename functions for testing and ran into similar difficulties with APD.

Finally hit on the right Google query and found another option: Sebastian Bergmann's [test_helpers extension](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers) -- it has its own `rename_function()` that seems to work just fine, as well as some other handy helpers for intercepting and mocking things.

Bonus - a relatively painless install process:

```
$ pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
$ pecl install phpunit/test_helpers
```

And then add `extension=test_helpers.so` to your php.ini