# Redeclaring the expects() function on PHPUnit mocks

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm stubbing a class in PHPUnit. I need to stub a method on that class called `expects`. However, that method already exists on the PHPUnit mocking base class. How would I circumvent that?
It obviously throws because I'm trying to redeclare `expects` (`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Mock_Inlet_399f0eba::expects()`)

```
$inlet = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(Inlet::class);
```

If I tried to stub a method called `method`, I could do...

```
$inlet->expects($this->any())->method('method')->willReturn([Foo::class]);
```

...as the mock is placed on `InvocationMocker` instead of the plain `MockObject`.

Is there a similar workaround for methods called `expects`, or will I have to either rename the method or mock it with some other mocking framework?

Comment: have you tried this http://php.net/manual/de/function.override-function.php ? or using namespaces ? namespace MyNamespace {
        function expects($object) 
        { ...

Comment: Mocks doesn't care about namespaces. Also the `override_function` is specific to APD. Thanks for your willingness to help anyway!

Comment: FYI I renamed `expects` to `expected`. Leaving the question open though, it'd be interesting to have an answer to this, even though it's an extreme edge case.

Comment: It should be possible to use [Decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377664/php-how-is-it-possible-to-rename-methods) for 'renaming' mock methods.

Comment: Nice idea @BVengerov. I'm not sure how that'd behave with typehinting, but I'll give it a shot when I get back to the project.

Comment: @Dencker aren't all edge cases extreme by definition?